# Rancher: How to set system-reserved and kube-resrved resources per node?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, rancher

In rancher we can set `kube-reserved` and `system-reserved` resources under `services -> kubelet -> extra_args` section of the cluster config.
But how can we assign **per node** (different reserve amounts per node)?
(Let's say we have nodes with different resource amounts, so we need to have different reservation amounts per each node)

Answer (score 0):

in rke2 cluster you can pass kubelet flags in
/etc/rancher/rke2/config.yaml like this:

.... (omitted)
`kubelet_arg: - "key=value"`
....
before doing any changes make sure to drain the node, stop rke2/k3s service